# Oracle Max Open Cursors - What does table_ mean?

Tags: oracle, cursors, max-connections

We're encountering a lot of maximum open cursors  recently so we ran a query to check for the maximum open cursors.

The query to check for open cursors looks something like this

```
select * from v$open_cursor where sid in (select s.sid from v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$session s where a.statistic# = b.statistic#  and s.sid=a.sid and b.name = 'opened cursors current' and s.username is not null and a.value >= 2);
```

However, I'm getting a lot of table_ in open cursor types. I'd like to know what the table_104_11_1a944_0_0_0 means.

Thanks!

```
000000064C7FDE28    8   PPHXQA  0000000606BBF490    2152991254  3r72urk0582hq   table_104_11_1a944_0_0_0            OPEN    00000006062ABAF0
000000064DD98D78    5450    PPHXQA  0000000606BBF490    2152991254  3r72urk0582hq   table_104_11_1a944_0_0_0            OPEN    00000006062ABAF0
000000065111A9F0    1825    PPHXQA  0000000606BBF490    2152991254  3r72urk0582hq   table_104_11_1a944_0_0_0            OPEN    00000006062ABAF0
000000065111A9F0    1825    PPHXQA  0000000606BBF490    2152991254  3r72urk0582hq   table_104_11_1a944_0_0_0            OPEN    00000006062ABAF0
000000064E13BE58    6348    PPHXQA  00000002C7849DE8    3991014065  2w2bchmqy42pj   select sys_context('USERENV','SESSIONID') from dual         DICTIONARY LOOKUP CURSOR CACHED 00000005F9DD90B8
000000064D2C0158    2740    PPHXDEV 00000002C7849DE8    3991014065  2w2bchmqy42pj   select sys_context('USERENV','SESSIONID') from dual         DICTIONARY LOOKUP CURSOR CACHED 00000005F9DD90B8
0000000651BF56E0    4533    PPHXQA  00000002C7849DE8    3991014065  2w2bchmqy42pj   select sys_context('USERENV','SESSIONID') from dual         DICTIONARY LOOKUP CURSOR CACHED 00000005F9DD90B8
652337700   6333    PPHXQA  00000005FA205090    3586526165  0jsamwzawc2yp   select count(*) as y0_ from TBL_SPO this_ inner join TBL_ACC            DICTIONARY LOOKUP CURSOR CACHED 00000002EEDD2600
651858870   3629    PPHXQA  0000000617B35488    673844243   9g485acn2n30m   select col#,intcol#,reftyp,stabid,expctoid from refcon$ wher            DICTIONARY LOOKUP CURSOR CACHED 000000061771DF70
0000000651BE2F90    4551    PPHXQA  0000000617B35488    673844243   9g485acn2n30m   select col#,intcol#,reftyp,stabid,expctoid from refcon$ wher            DICTIONARY LOOKUP CURSOR CACHED 000000061771DF70
000000064D2C0158    2740    PPHXQA  0000000617B35488    673844243   9g485acn2n30m   select col#,intcol#,reftyp,stabid,expctoid from refcon$ wher            DICTIONARY LOOKUP CURSOR CACHED 000000061771DF70
0000000650D75840    929 PPHXQA  0000000617B35488    673844243   9g485acn2n30m   select col#,intcol#,reftyp,stabid,expctoid from refcon$ wher            DICTIONARY LOOKUP CURSOR CACHED 000000061771DF70
000000064CF253B8    1834    PPHXQA  0000000617B35488    673844243   9g485acn2n30m   select col#,intcol#,reftyp,stabid,expctoid from refcon$ wher            DICTIONARY LOOKUP CURSOR CACHED 000000061771DF70
000000064CB9EE38    908 SYS 0000000617B35488    673844243   9g485acn2n30m   select col#,intcol#,reftyp,stabid,expctoid from refcon$ wher            DICTIONARY LOOKUP CURSOR CACHED 000000061771DF70
000000064DD98D78    5450    PPHXQA  00000005F96EFBA8    1258425617  59h19b15h438j   table_104_d_1a9f9_0_0_0         OPEN    00000005FA7F7AF0
0000000651BE7130    4547    PPHXQA  00000005F96EFBA8    1258425617  59h19b15h438j   table_104_d_1a9f9_0_0_0         OPEN    00000005FA7F7AF0
000000065111A9F0    1825    PPHXQA  00000005F96EFBA8    1258425617  59h19b15h438j   table_104_d_1a9f9_0_0_0         OPEN    00000005FA7F7AF0
652337700   6333    PPHXQA  00000005F96EFBA8    1258425617  59h19b15h438j   table_104_d_1a9f9_0_0_0         OPEN    00000005FA7F7AF0
00000006518567A0    3631    PPHXQA  00000005F96EFBA8    1258425617  59h19b15h438j   table_104_d_1a9f9_0_0_0         OPEN    00000005FA7F7AF0
00000006514AF520    2737    PPHXQA  00000005F96EFBA8    1258425617  59h19b15h438j   table_104_d_1a9f9_0_0_0         OPEN    00000005FA7F7AF0
6.51E+06    1835    PPHXQA  00000005F96EFBA8    1258425617  59h19b15h438j   table_104_d_1a9f9_0_0_0         OPEN    00000005FA7F7AF0
000000064C7FDE28    8   PPHXQA  00000005F96EFBA8    1258425617  59h19b15h438j   table_104_d_1a9f9_0_0_0         OPEN    00000005FA7F7AF0
0000000651F8A210    5445    PPHXQA  00000006074AB8E8    1410600294  284x39ja183b6   select cast(wt.batch_id as VARCHAR2(200)) from tbl_bills_pay            DICTIONARY LOOKUP CURSOR CACHED 00000002BEC3BF70
000000064CB9EE38    908 SYS 0000000617DF7BB8    2627079617  fk09qjuf9c3f1   select cdb from v$database          DICTIONARY LOOKUP CURSOR CACHED 0000000617DF6708
0000000651BE7130    4547    PPHXQA  00000005F96D7520    157552065   c84x6qh4q83f1   table_104_11_1aa53_0_0_0            OPEN    00000005F93B2370
000000064C7FDE28    8   PPHXQA  00000005F96D7520    157552065   c84x6qh4q83f1   table_104_11_1aa53_0_0_0            OPEN    00000005F93B2370
652337700   6333    PPHXQA  00000005F96D7520    157552065   c84x6qh4q83f1   table_104_11_1aa53_0_0_0            OPEN    00000005F93B2370
6.51E+06    1835    PPHXQA  00000005F96D7520    157552065   c84x6qh4q83f1   table_104_11_1aa53_0_0_0            OPEN    00000005F93B2370
0000000651BF77B0    4531    PPHXQA  00000005F96D7520    157552065   c84x6qh4q83f1   table_104_11_1aa53_0_0_0            OPEN    00000005F93B2370
```

Comment: Nested table types. See https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3311300131016

Comment: Hi, I'm having table_104, nested types according to the thread are table_1_

Comment: The number doesn't matter

Comment: It seems to be a consistent 504 across environment. 4 seems to indicate lob while 1 is nested tables